# the multi part identifier could not be bound while using UPDATE query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to update email address from table `B_A` to table `A` if email address is different in table `B_A` is different from table `A`.

the query I am trying is :

```
UPDATE A
SET Email = ( select [Email Address] from [B_A] where A.Email <> [B_A].[Email_Address])
where A.ID = [B_A].[ID]
```

and my error is : 
`the multi part identifier [B_A].[ID] could not be bound`

how do I normalize this query to run?

Comment: Some one please help me.

Comment: do you have some more info about your schema?  does B_A have a column called 'Email Address' with a space, or should it be just Email.

Comment: I have 2 tables, A( ID, Email), B_A(ID, Email). In A, an Email has been duplicated lot many times, So I am comparing ID of A with ID of B_A, and updating email address of A when ID is same and Email address doesn't match.

Comment: It is "Email Address", with a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem looks like you are referencing a table from your inner query in your outer query.  The outer statement is not aware of the B_A table because you have only defined on the inner one.

You could try something like this:

```
UPDATE A
JOIN B_A on A.id = B_A.id
SET A.email = B_A.email
WHERE A.email <> B_A.email
```

Not sure if UPDATE JOIN is available in SQL Server, but that syntax will work on other dbs.

Comment: I realize that. But I have not been able to come up to a reasonable solution to the problem. I am new to SQL queries with very minor experience working on it, and I have not been able to resolve this problem. Any guidance would be really helpful. Since this is not working, i have to do all the updates by using single update set command for the large dataset that i have.

Comment: UPDATE A
JOIN B_A on A.id = B.id 

it gives me error Incorrect Syntax near JOIN, says invalid column name for B_A ..